# How to verify the funtion $\Bbb{P}_{a}$ , defined as $\Bbb{P}_{a}(B) = \int_{B} f d\lambda$ for any Borel set B, is a probability measure

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory

I am trying some exercise on a measure theoretic probability text, and want to make sure if I am doing right.

The question is:

Let ($\Omega$, $\mathbf{F}$ , $\Bbb{P}$) be a probability space. Assume g : $\Omega \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ is a nonnegative measurable function and let f be a nonnegative measurable function on $\Bbb{R}$ such that  $\int f d\lambda$= 1. Then, verify that, for any Borel set B, if $\Bbb{P}_{a}(B) = \int_{B} f d\lambda$, then the function $\Bbb{P}_{a}$ is a probability measure.

My argument is:

- **Show $\Bbb{P}_{a}(\Omega)$ is equal to 1** : very trivial by one of our assumption $\int_{\Omega} f d\lambda$ = $\int f d\lambda$= 1.
- **Show $\Bbb{P}_{a}(\emptyset)$ is equal to 0** : $\int_{\emptyset} f d\lambda $ = $\int (f I_{\emptyset})d\lambda $ = $\int (0)d\lambda$ = 0, because the indicator variable $I_{\emptyset}$ is equal to zero for all $\omega \in  \Omega$
- **Assuming $A_{1}, A_{2}, ... $ are (possibly countably infinite ) disjoint $\mathbf{F}$-measurable sets, show its countable additivity:** This is the key part in this proof. As follows:
  $\Bbb{P}_{a}(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}{A_{i}})$ = $\int_{\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}{A_{i}}} f d\lambda $ = $\int (f I_{\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}{A_{i}}})d\lambda $ = $\int (f \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}I_{A_{i}})d\lambda $ = $\int (\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f I_{A_{i}})$ =? = $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \Bbb{P}_{a}(A_{i})$

For the countable additivity part, the third equality holds because the indicator $I_{\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}{A_{i}}}$ = 1 only when one of  $A_{i}$'s contains $\omega$ and the fact that $A_{i}$ 's are disjoint implies $I_{\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}{A_{i}}}$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}I_{A_{i}}$. Also, the fourth equality holds, because $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}I_{A_{i}}$ is either 0 or 1 (bounded), so that $f(\omega)\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}I_{A_{i}}(\omega) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f(\omega)I_{A_{i} }$, by the property of convergent series.

The definition of abstract integration we learned in class is $\int_{A} f d\lambda $ = $\int (f I_{A})d\lambda $ using indicator variable. So, I used this definition to derive those.

Let me know if I derived so far is wrong or missing anything..I d appreciate.

What I do not know:

the question mark part in countable additivity proof. I want to interchange the integration and infinite series, but I am not quite sure this is legal here. I learned the property of linearity of integration symbol, but as far as I know, it only holds for finite case. Can I extend it to infinite sum case?

We are going to learn MonotoneConvergenceThm(MCT) and Fatou's Lemma, but when this exercise is assigned, MCT is not covered also.

Answer (score 1):

In the last equality, you're using the following theorem:

> If $f_n:\Omega\to[0,\infty]$ is a sequence of measurable functions, then
> \begin{align}
> \int\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int f_n
> \end{align}

This is a consequence of the monotone convergence theorem, which says if you have a sequence of non-negative measurable functions $s_n$ which increase to a function $s$ (i.e $0\leq s_1\leq s_2\leq s_3\leq \dots \leq s:=\lim s_n$), then $\int s=\lim\int s_n$ (i.e you can interchange limits and integrals if the functions increase to a limit). Now, you just apply the monotone convergence theorem to the partial sums $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^nf_k$, and use the finite case.

Well, you mention that this is assigned before the monotone convergence theorem, which I find quite odd because this result is usually one of the first few applications of the monotone convergence theorem (after proving Fatou and DCT):)

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment! So, MCT should be used here. got it.